# Vertical align not proper to a label

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a list items. The list contains header, label, description. when I place draft label next to header, its not vertically centered to header text. Header text may come with 1 line or two lines.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7utemcfe/2/)

Html

```
<div class="container">
        <a href="" class="head">Hedline Text</a>
        <span class="label">Draft</span>
        <div class="meta">
            1246 Everett Avenue. Louisville. Kentucky. 40204. US
        </div>
        <p class="description">
            It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
    readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point 
    of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less making it look 
    like readable English.
        </p>
    </div>
```

Css:

```
.container { 
    padding: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.head {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.label {
    background: #eee;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 6px 5px;
}
```

[image: CSS Issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="" class="head">Hedline Text Hedline Hedline Text Hedline Hedline Text Hedline<span class="label">Draft</span></a>
    <div class="meta">
        1246 Everett Avenue. Louisville. Kentucky. 40204. US
    </div>
    <p class="description">
        It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point 
of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less making it look 
like readable English.
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container { 
    padding: 50px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.head {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.label {
    background: #eee;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.meta {
    color: grey;
}
```

[Updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7utemcfe/4/)

Comment: Thanks @Matei, but still label is taking the same space, My problem is header and label are same height, then I calculate the margin-top to next line based on the header height. but label coming little below. so the next line taking extra space. here is my vertical rhythm calculation is not working.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/7utemcfe/4/ I will update my answer if so

Comment: Yes Metai, This is what I want exactly. Update your answer. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because both of the elements in question are `inline` (`.head` is set to `display: inline-block;` and `.label` is a `span` which defaults to `display: inline;`) and are therefore being vertically aligned to the default `baseline`.

To vertically align them to the middle add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.head` and `.label`.

```css
.container {
  padding: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.head {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.label {
  background: #eee;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 6px 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.meta {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="" class="head">Hedline Text</a>
  <span class="label">Draft</span>
  <div class="meta">
    1246 Everett Avenue. Louisville. Kentucky. 40204. US
  </div>
  <p class="description">
    It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less making it look like readable English.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
.label{
 Padding-top: -5 px;
 }
```